# How to sort pandas DataFrame on multiple columns using separate sorting functions for each column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I am trying to find a generic way to sort a DataFrame on multiple columns, where each column is sorted by a different arbitrary sort function.

For example, for input I might have

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,"Basic",6],[1,"Intermediate",9],[2,"Intermediate",6],[0,"Advanced",6],[0,"Basic",2],[1, 'Advanced', 6], [0,"Basic",3], ], columns=['Hour','Level','Value'])

        Hour    Level   Value
0   2   Basic           6
1   1   Intermediate    9
2   2   Intermediate    6
3   0   Advanced        6
4   0   Basic           2
5   1   Advanced        6
6   0   Basic           3
```

and I want my output to be

```
    Hour    Level   Value
0   0   Advanced        6
1   0   Basic           3
2   0   Basic           2
3   1   Advanced        6
4   1   Intermediate    9
5   2   Intermediate    6
6   2   Basic           6
```

I might have a function map as such

```
lambdaMap = {
"Hour": lambda x: x,
"Level": lambda x: [['Advanced', 'Intermediate', 'Basic'].index(l) for l in x]
"Value": lambda x: -x
}
```

I can apply any one of the sorting functions individually:

```
sortValue="Hour"
df.sort_values(by=sortValue, key=lambdaMap[sortValue])
```

I could create a loop to apply each sort successively:

```
for (column, func) in lambdaSort.items():
    df = df.sort_values(by=column, key=func)
```

But none of these will create the output I'm looking for.  Is this even possible?  There are a lot of examples with how to achieve similar things for specific instances, but I'm curious if there is a way to achieve this generically, for use in the creation of API and/or general support libraries.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert to [`categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) and do a sort:

```
df['Level'] = pd.Categorical(df['Level'],['Advanced', 'Intermediate', 'Basic'],
              ordered=True)
out = df.sort_values(['Hour','Level','Value'],ascending=[True,True,False])
```

---

```
print(out)

   Hour         Level  Value
3     0      Advanced      6
6     0         Basic      3
4     0         Basic      2
5     1      Advanced      6
1     1  Intermediate      9
2     2  Intermediate      6
0     2         Basic      6
```

Comment: This will solve this specific instance, but I'm more interested in a general solution that will take any arbitrary object of fields and functions.  For instance, what if I had a more complicated sort function that wasn't categorial or numerical.  I am open to suggestions for a object structure that might help achieve this: e.g. including information about what type of sort each function is.  Sill, curious how this would work for any sort function, no matter how complex.

Comment: @crackernutter There is no builtin for such. Its very specific. Though from pandas 1.1, you get a [key](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) argument much like python's `sorted()`